# Run predefined search sub-query in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am using a splunk query which always includes specific sub-query:

> host="aaa" OR host ="bbb" OR host="ccc"

So for instance I do 2 different searches like:

```
host="aaa" OR host ="bbb" OR host="ccc" "MyClass" "id=3"
host="aaa" OR host ="bbb" OR host="ccc" "MyClass" "id=6"
```

and so on.
Is there a way to save somewhere predefined part of the query and reuse it? So I could run my searches like

```
myquery="hosts_include"  "MyClass" "id=3"
myquery="hosts_include"  "MyClass" "id=6"
```

Or any other syntax which will simplify my query so I do not have to copy and paste the redundant sub query every time.

Comment: fwiw ... if you want the same field (eg `host`) to *simultaneously* equal three different values ("aaa","bbb", & "ccc"), your search will *always* return 0 results

Comment: good point, I have changed my post to contain more meaningfull query. Although it does not change the value of the primary question itself, which is just runnig always same sub-query (no matter what query that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a macro.  Go to Settings->Advanced search->Macros and define a new macro (call it "hosts", for example).  Then invoke the macro in your queries by enclosing the name in backticks.

```
`hosts` "MyClass" "id=3"
`hosts` "MyClass" "id=6"
```

Answer (score 1):

@[RichG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227420/richg)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75511258/4418) is a good one

However, you may also want to look at making a lookup table so you can do something like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp [| inputlookup myhosts.csv ] "MyClass" id IN(3,6)
```

If you "always" want to look for hosts out of a list (inclusively), using an manageable lookup table is likely going to be easier than having to remember to update a macro like `myhosts`

Macros definitely work - I use them quite frequently as search shortcuts myself (I use one on practically every search I run in one workspace that fills-in the index and sourcetype so I only have to type 8 characters instead of about 35), but I suspect a lookup table will be simpler to manage and run faster for you

Comment: That is a great suggestion for my future search queries, because in fact the hosts addresses are under changes. Also for different environments I have different sets of hosts.